# Trying to Port forward for a game server but All devices in my house have the same IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

Setting up a Minecraft server right now and trying to port forward.

I've followed all the steps correctly but it's still not working. I also noticed that every device has the same public IP when I google "What's my IP".

Does anybody have a solution to work around this?

Router: Honor Router 3

*EDIT:

I've forwarded 192.168.3.22, which, if I'm correct, should be the "iPv4 address" of the computer hosting the server?
[Image of the IP I've forwarded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6hUz.png)

Is this correct?

If so, which IP are people supposed to connect to?

Googling told me it's the IP you get from Goolging "What's my IP"

Trying to connect to the IP this gives me doesn't work, I can't connect to the server.

Furthermore, when I Google "What's my IP", my IP is the same regardless of whether I'm on my phone, computer, or the server computer.

**EDIT 2:
I'm pretty sure I didn't forward my WAN IP, the "What's my IP" result is for connecting to the server. The IP I forwarded is the 192.168 one in the above screenshot.

I'm not sure I understand some of the comments here? Is this the correct IP to be forwarding?

If it's correct then have I done the steps correctly? Why can I still not connect to my server using the "What's my IP" IP?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have one WAN IP with which you connect to the internet. Every device in your LAN network will have a LAN IP, typically in the range 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x (can also be in 10.x.x.x etc). You have to forward the port to the LAN IP address your minecraft server is on. You can see your IP by opening a command prompt and typing "ipconfig".

Comment: @Silbee Thanks for the response, edited the post a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: Do note that most consumer-grade routers do not understand or support NAT hairpinning. This basically means that if you connect to your WAN IP address, the router sends the connection to the internet and does not expect that to be its own device, and as such the connection times out. For that reason, a server hosted locally should always use the LAN IP address of that pc, not the WAN IP Address. The WAN IP address and portforwarding is only used when someone from the internet wants to joint.

Comment: What LPChip said. Give someone the ip address and port to connect to (the ip address you get from What's My IP). See if they can get in. Its also normal all your devices show the same 'Whats my IP' ip, because thats your WAN IP. Inside your own network, stuff uses Network Address Translation (NAT) to make sure packets arrive correctly. It could also be that your ISP blocks the port you are forwarding (often ISPs block all ports under 1024) or that your ISP uses Carrier Grade NAT. In that last case, you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what I'm doing wrong here, I'm pretty sure I'm already using my LAN IP. Is it not the 192.168 one that I have in the screenshot?

The Router I'm using doesn't allow me to enter in my own values for the IP, but only allows me to choose from a list of devices, so I just selected the computer that the server was hosted on.

Comment: It looks like you have set things up correctly. So that leaves either a software firewall on your laptop or your ISP uses carrier grade NAT. That last thing means your ISP is doing basicly what LAN's do and hide multiple hosts behind one IP, typically done because they run out of IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to know if my ISP does do carrier grade NAT or do I just gotta call em? Also is "Software firewall" different to the regular windows firewall? I've allowed port 25565 for inbound and outbound for both TCP and UDP already. Is there another firewall specific to Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got mixed up somewhere about which IP you need to forward your port to.

If you want to allow people to connect to your Minecraft server, you need to forward that port to your local IP (it should be either 10.0.0.x or 192.168.x.x).

Then you can use your *public* IP to allow people to connect.

At a (very) basic level, they will use your public IP to connect. When that connection reaches your router, it will lookup the port you have forwarded, and will know to direct the Minecraft traffic to your server

EDIT: The screenshot you have put up looks like it is configured correctly now. So a couple more things to check. Is your server running? have you got a firewall on your laptop that you need to configure to allow connections?

Comment: thanks for the response, I probably did get confused. I updated the post a bit to show what I currently have, it hasn't been changed since I first made this post.

Comment: Just saw your edit, I haven't changed anything so it was probably configured properly to begin with then...

Server is running, my friends are already playing on it via Hamachi. That said I aim to open the server up without Hamachi, hence why I'm trying to port forward.

Firewall already allows 25565 in both TCP/UDP for inbound and outbound.